# click DOM element when component updates props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, click

I have a component that has a click event on `componentDidMount` lifecycle method.

I need the div clicked every time the render of the component triggers.

My problem is that `componentDidMount` only fires once and when the component is re-rendered, the click event is not fired.

I didn't find any other lifecycle method where the click event would work.

Is it possible to do it in any other way?

The click method:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
        audioPlayer: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.audio)
    }, () => {
      this.state.audioPlayer.ontimeupdate = () => { this.timeUpdated() };
      this.state.audioPlayer.onprogress = () => { this.progressUpdated() };
      if(this.props.playing) {
        this.divElement.click();
      }
    });
  }
```

The div referenced:

```
<div className='player__control__icons--play'>
    <div ref={div => this.divElement = div}  className='player__control__icon' onClick={this.togglePlay.bind(this)}>
        <Play />
    </div>
    {skipButtons}
</div>
```

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate that method should be what you want

Answer (score 0):

I think both `componentWillReceiveProps` and `componentDidUpdate` can access refs (not 100% sure about the first one tho). `componentWillReceiveProps` makes it easy to check if the prop actually changed, e.g.

https://developmentarc.gitbooks.io/react-indepth/content/life_cycle/update/component_will_receive_props.html

```
componentWillReceiveProps (nextProps) {
  if (!this.props.playing && nextProps.playing) {
    this.divElement.click();
  }
}
```

Also as a sidenote, unless you really rely on the native click event, it is usually cleaner to call the click handler directly, in your case `this.togglePlay`. Again, I don't know the implementation of this function, so maybe you need the click event for some reason, but in most cases its not really necessary :)

Comment: Thank you! Your comment really helped me to solve the problem!